# Post counter Daily,weekly,monthly,all time php & mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I got a website with several posts/articles which I can track by last 24h,last week,last month and all time views for each post.

I save the timestamp on each view in the db. When someone opens the home page I loop these timestamps and save them accordingly to the last 24h/last week/last month/all time in the db.
This works "good" (but problem).

**NOW THE PROBLEM:**

What if I have 5000 posts!  the php script has to loop all 5000 posts and do the savings which is causing performance problems.  The Site won't show up as soon the function is done.
I already got an Error Message "Allowed memory size exhausted ...".

How can I solve this problem?  Is there any solution.

It's quite important to run this function on when open the home page to get the exact counter datas.

If I would do this function only on post view and then just for this post the datas wouldn't be accurate.  Imagine the post has not been viewed for several days, the counter datas wouldn't be updated.

*Note: It's for a Wordpress theme which isn't very important in this case.*

Comment: First, you should not be doing something like this every time somebody opens your page.... setup a cron job or something to do it only every so often (once a day?).

Comment: Second, are you sure you have to loop all posts? Sometimes it's OK for the counters not to be updated to the last second. A cron job, as @sachleen suggested would be helpful, even if it's once every few minutes - or page refresh, whichever comes later.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  The problem is I can not work with a cron job because it will be for a wordpress theme and the users of this theme would need to set up a cronjob and the won't have the knowledge and 'nervs' for this.  I need to find another possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using WordPress's cron function **wp_cron** ([here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron))

*NOTE:* It does rely on access to fire, unlike a "true cron job".

Also, look into using **Transients API**. Transients make a HUGE performance increase! ([here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API))

---

The Transients API, in simple terms, caches a loop. So instead of cycling 5000 posts EVERY TIME, it will loop *once* then set some data. On subsequent loads, it will fetch that cached data. If the data is NOT there or is EXPIRED, it will then loop the posts to cache new data.

Check out this psuedo-code

```
if ( false === ( $query = get_transient( 'query' ) ) ) {
    // It wasn't there, so regenerate the data and save the transient
    $query = new WP_Query( '//Your Loop Stuff' );
    set_transient( 'query', $query );
}
$timestamps = $query->TIMESTAMP(or whatever you use);
```